# Flutter modular package - DI for BLOC

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-modular

I need to bind my dependencies through the bind property. The thing is that when I push a new page, it generates a new context without my previous defined provider. I went through the documentation here [link to docs](https://modular.flutterando.com.br/docs/flutter_modular/module)

My app has a Router module which is the main module for my app

[image]

My AuthRouter is a module containing 2 routes. I am accessing the home properly and the bloc instances are dispatched as expected.

[image]

But when I execute a pushedNamed to the perfilPage the provider my blocs are not found. I think I am missing something but I do not know what exactly is.

The error is this this

[image]